# Dependency of test cases in Smart Contract Testing

Tags: javascript, blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts, truffle

I have a question on the **dependency of the test cases**.

Assume that all test cases are written in JavaScript, how can I figure out the dependent relationship between test cases.

I use the keyword `it.only(...)` to execute a single test case (it failed), but I get the opposite result (passing) when I execute the test case with other test cases together.

Is there any way to detect the dependency?

Thx in advance.

Comment: Why there should be dependency between test cases ? You have to arrange all necessary preconditions and inputs before each test case.

Comment: Hi @BadisMerabet, yes, you're right. Also in my mind, **the test cases should be independent**. However, I test in the real smart contract project and find that dependency causes different test result really happens so it confuses me. I am new to smart contract. I googled but didn't find any helpful information. :-( Please kindly advise if you have any thoughts on it.

Comment: try to look at `before` or `beforeEach`